# Questions to appear in the same location

Tags: javascript, html

My form has many Questions. I'm looking for a way to have all my questions appear in one single location rather than one below the other as seen in my code below -

```
<p>  <SPAN ID="FirstQuestion"> Blah Blah Blah </p>       

 <button class="button1" button onclick="Function1()"><span>NEXT</span></button>


 <p>  <SPAN ID="SecondQuestion"> Blah Blah Blah  <br> </p>      

 <button class="button2" button onclick="Function2()"><span>NEXT</span></button>

<script> 

function Function1() {

 $( "#SecondQuestion" ).css('visibility', 'visible');
 $( "#FirstQuestion" ).css('visibility', 'hidden');

 </script>
```

I already have almost 30 Questions in the form. I do not want these questions to appear one below other instead once the first question is read and when NEXT button is clicked, the second question should appear on the same location were the first one appeared(of course hiding the first question)
Can this be done or do i have to create separate pages for each question and then link it.
Hope I'm clear.

Comment: Are you tied to that HTML?

Comment: Yes. When the page loads, only the first question should appear and when i hit next, the second question should appear in the same location were first question appeared.

Comment: I understand your requirements, but with that HTML it's not all that easy. And - to my eyes - it's a little bit horrible, that is probably a purely personal stylistic thing, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visibility hidden will only hide the element, but the element will retain the space it has occupied on the screen. You should use the CSS styling called display and toggle with block and none.

```
 $( "#SecondQuestion" ).css('display', 'block');
 $( "#FirstQuestion" ).css('display', 'none');
```

EDIT:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="question"> BLAH Blah Blah </p>
<p class="question" style="display:none;"> Blah BLAH Blah</p>

<button class="button1" button onclick="nextQuestion()"><span>NEXT</span></button>


       

<script> 
var count = 0;
function nextQuestion() {
  var currentQuestion = $(".question")[count];
  var nextQuestion = $(".question")[++count];
  $(currentQuestion).hide();
  $(nextQuestion).show();
}
</script>
```

Comment: You explained it very well thanks.. But I'm not able to implement this. My form should have only one question at a time. The initial page will have only one question and when i hit next, the next question should appear in that same place.. Hope I'm making it clear

Comment: Okay I changed the HTML quite a bit. I removed the ids and used the class with ".question". This will allow you to have a complete list of all the questions and when the user clicks next it will show the next question. The hide function makes the element display none and the show function makes the element display block. Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Thanks to everyone who helped me.. I got it working from all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

`visibility` only masks the element, leaving the space it takes up. Perhaps you want `.show()`, `.hide()`?

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things wrong here:

1. Your mark up is not right.
2. If you write click event for every question, what if there are 100's of questions

I tried to simulate what you are trying to do 
check the following code snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var count=1;
  $('.question:not(:first-child)').addClass('hide');
  $('.question .next').bind('click',function(){
   // alert(count);
        var $prevQuestion=$('.question:nth-child('+count+')');
        $prevQuestion.removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
        count=count+1;
       //alert(count);
        var $currQuestion=$('.question:nth-child('+count+')');
        $currQuestion.removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
  });
});
```

```css
.hide{
  display:none;
  
}
.show{
  display:block;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="question">
  <p>question1</p>
  <input type="button" class="next" value="next"/>
</div>

<div class="question">
  <p>question2</p>
  <input type="button" class="next" value="next"/>
</div>

<div class="question">
  <p>question3</p>
  <input type="button" class="next" value="next"/>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: While I agree with your points, you may want to take the time to explain why the code "*mark up is not right*" in order that the OP might learn something.